# MSBuild - Post-Build capture binaries regardless of build configuration or framework?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

Project A (a web app) depends on Project B (an exe) - I need to copy the exe using Project A's post-build event from `bin` of Project A to wwwroot of Project A.

I want to copy a binary from wherever it's dropped (bin/debug or bin/release or bin/debug/netcoreapp2.0 etc) without knowing the build configuration or target framework.  Right now I'm doing this:

```
copy /Y $(ProjectDir)bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0\app.exe $(ProjectDir)wwwroot\exe\app.exe
```

Which works great locally, but when it builds somewhere else with a `Release` configuration, it fails.  I could use some if/then checks but I'd rather have a macro that replaces the `$(ProjectDir)bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0` chunk of the path so I'm always grabbing what I need without any knowledge of configuration/framework.

I've tried to use `$(OutDir)` and `$(TargetDir)` with no luck - these just give me the non-`bin` path.

Which macro should I be using?

Comment: As an option, you can set OutDir property to the desired location and skip the post-build step altogether, e. g. `<OutDir>..\wwwroot\exe\</OutDir>` in a PropertyGroup not conditioned on anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(TargetPath)` should be the complete path to your output executable. Not sure what you mean about `$(TargetDir)` giving you the 'non-bin' path.
Not really a C# question BTW.

Comment: I replace the above with `copy /Y $(TargetPath)app.exe $(ProjectDir)wwwroot\exe\app.exe` and I get `Could not find file 'C:\Users\me\source\repos\App\wwwroot\exe\app.exe` - any idea why?  I'm trying to copy from *wherever the binaries are dropped*

Comment: You don't need "app.exe" - that's included in `$(TargetPath)`. But you may need to ensure the folder at `$(ProjectDir)wwwroot\exe` exists with `mkdir -p`

Comment: I need to specify the EXE.  Project A (a web app) depends on Project B (an exe) - I need to copy the exe using Project A's post-build event from `bin` of Project A to `wwwroot` of Project A.

Comment: If the project B is in a different directory then none of project A's macros are going to tell you where it is . Why can't you do this in the post-build rule for project B?

Comment: Since A depends on B, b's exe (app.exe) is dropped in A's `bin`.  Really, all I need is a macro that replaces the above `$(ProjectDir)bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0`.  Does this not exist?  I could do a post-build in Project B but then I have to worry about finding A's `wwwroot` (facing the same issue - how to find `bin` without knowing config/framework).

Comment: But at least A's wwwroot\exe\ path doesn't change with build type, so that's an easy problem to solve. As it is, I'll repeat what I said - none of project A's macros are going to tell what the full output path for project B is, it may use a completely convention for generating that path.

Comment: Re your "facing the same issue" - that's not apparent from what you initially described, but can't you configure project A to always use the same output directory regardless of build type? That's generally the norm for web-application type projects anyway.

Comment: A doesn't need to know B's output path since A depends on B and B's exe gets dropped in A's bin folder...  And no, if you build in debug configuration then it gets dropped to bin/debug, release is bin/release.

Comment: Your initial questions showed `$(ProjectDir)wwwroot\exe\app.exe` as the local you need to copy to - i.e., it doesn't change depending on build configuration. So put this copy command as a post-build rule for project B, where you can use $(TargetPath) to get the source path.